# What is the word for "other people's thinking"?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

For years I've been using the word **dogma** to describe other people's thinking. This is an example of how I used it:

> Don't get caught up in other people's dogma...live your own truth...

Basically to not get hung up on expectations of others for you to be thin, smart, sexy, successful under their definition, rich, etc. To find existence outside of the bounds of socially-defined morality (which I call **dogma**). I am wondering if **dogma** was the correct word or if there is something better to describe this type of peer pressure or expectation.

**Dogma** seems to be defined as related to religion, but I am referring more to humanity in general. Thoughts?

Comment: I made up a word for exactly this during a magic mushroom trip :D

Comment: "dogma" is a set of beliefs, not someone's thinking. That would be opinion. Is what a person's beliefs are and what he believes in is what you're interested in?

Comment: I think *dogma* perfectly apt here, albeit somewhat metaphorical. Literally, yes, it refers to the whole of what some church has laid down as stuff that its members are required to believe. But metaphorically it can refer to stuff that people collectively believe without critically questioning it. I suspect @vickyace's "set of beliefs" vs. "someone's thinking" is a distinction without a difference, like [First Gravedigger](http://www.opensourceshakespeare.org/views/plays/play_view.php?WorkID=hamlet&Act=5&Scene=1&Scope=scene)'s "to act, to do, and to perform."

Comment: If you even remember what the word was, @ArmenԾիրունյան, could you favor us with it?

Comment: @BrianDonovan I think "beliefs" should be used instead and avoid this quest all together.  :)

Comment: Although typically used in religious context, "[dogma](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/dogma)" doesn't necessarily refer specifically to religious beliefs.  As long as you use the word in full awareness of its religious overtones, it could serve well in the kind of context you describe.  Take care, however, as "dogma" is a fairly strong word -- much stronger than "beliefs" or "thinking", for example.  A risk of your words being taken more strongly than you intend attends its use.

Comment: @BrianDonovan I agree that it is an excellent metaphorical use of *dogma*. But just going back to the OP's question, they were asking specifically if it was a word for *other people's thinking*. The answer to that is definitely *no*. The metaphorical sense which we have just discovered could equally apply to oneself. In no way at all is *dogma* something that uniquely describes the ideas of "other people".

Answer (score 1):

Creed - an idea or set of beliefs that guides the actions of a person or group

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/creed

Ideology -  1.a systematic body of concepts especially about human life or culture

2. a manner or the content of thinking characteristic of an individual, group, or culture

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ideology

Also try [tenet](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tenet)

Answer (score 0):

While *dogma* is apt enough as a metaphor (from religion) for the whole mass of opinion that the mass of people accept all too uncritically, another possible term is *bullshit.* As philosopher Harry Frankfurt famously declared in [his essay on the subject](http://www.stoa.org.uk/topics/bullshit/pdf/on-bullshit.pdf), *bullshit* is definable by just this lack of critical concern about whether a belief or assertion corresponds to reality or not.

> It is just this lack of connection to a concern with truth—this indifference to how things really are—that I regard as of the essence of
>   bullshit.

Of course, this is one of

> the words that you can't say, that you're not supposed to say *all the time*

as [George Carlin](http://law2.umkc.edu/faculty/projects/ftrials/conlaw/filthywords.html) memorably put it, which may be a consideration underlying your preference for *dogma.*